# Deletion of record from Microsoft CRM Based on three fields(KINGSWAYSOFT)

Tags: dynamics-crm, ssis-2012, kingswaysoft

I have flatfile source and dynamics crm destination.I have to delete a record from CRM based on Title(text), Startdate(text) and userid(lookup field in CRM) which is given as input from flatfile.Can you suggest how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at our [Premium Lookup](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack/help-manual/premium-data-flow-components/premium-lookup) component in the [SSIS Productivity Pack](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack), which allows you to perform a lookup against your CRM source. The Premium Lookup component takes two inputs - **Primary Input** and **Lookup Table Input**. In your case, you can specify the flat file source component as your Primary Input and use CRM Source component as the Lookup Table Input. With that being done, you should be able to get the corresponded records in the Matched Rows ouput, which can be used to pushed to the CRM Destination component and perform a Delete action. Hope this helps.