# SSIS Kingswaysoft: Delete in destination table won't work when record does not exist in another source

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

I'm using Kingswaysoft in SSIS and trying to delete records that are not existing in (non-CRM) source.

However, upon running the package, instead of deleting the record, it was redirect to error log.

How do I make Delete functionality works using Kingswaysoft?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46412088/7920473

Comment: Can you share the error message that you are receiving in the error output? You will have to troubleshoot based on the error message received. Like @ArunVinoth has suggested above, you may consider a lookup strategy to find out the ID values before you actually send to the CRM destination component. There are many different ways of doing it, using our Premium Lookup component is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Create Dynamics CRM Source same as your CRM Destination.
Use FetchXML to select the records you want to delete.
[Here is a blog](http://danielcai.blogspot.ca/2012/05/use-ssis-to-perform-batch-update-or.html)